In K8s gitops kutomize - Is there a way to overwrite service's base yaml configuration with more environment specific
I'm new to K8s, gitops and kustomize. Our gitops folder structure has "base" folder which contains base configuration files and also "envs" folder in which we keep kustomization.yaml files with patches for various environments.
The problem is, one of our environment configuration vary a lot from the base configuration, thus kustomization yaml file would have hundreds of lines of patches to base configuration. Apart from creaing a separate repository and apart from defining hundreds-line kustomization file patches, is there any other way to patch/replace base yaml files?
Tried patches, but the file would have hundreds of lines:
`patches:
- target:
    kind: Ingress
    name: gateway
  patch: |-
    - op: replace
...`


If those specific files vary greatly between the base and your environments, why not just remove them from the base? Then each environment can provide the necessary configuration directly, without needing to patch anything.

Probably not what you want to hear but this is the limit of Kustomize approach. There's no "variable replacement" like in a template approach. You may consider Helm if it better suits your needs. Helm can be used through Kustomize to benefit from both worlds.
